# Resident Evil 2 intro inverted scene?

Tags: video-games, resident-evil

[image]

It’s a picture from the *Resident Evil 2* remake intro movie.

The camera is inverted, correct?
There’s an “exit” sign, and what are those things the blue sets are pointing?

Is it inside a building?

Answer (score -1):

The camera is surely inverted about 93 degrees clockwise.

However, whether that view intends to continue the earlier effect of also looking through the same reflected car mirror is unknown; it’s likely not the same car showing this vantage point, and no second mirror was ever shown immediately preceding this new scene.

It doesn’t necessarily have to be a mirror, we also could be looking through a transparent or translucent window or screen of some sort and seeing the “backside” of the “Exit” sign and the other objects. In fact, this would support the “blurry” effect which pretty much obscures the legibility of the other objects adjacent to the “Exit” sign.

Comment: It’s not a window inside a building?

I think its a light bulb above the exit sign. There’s a circle with a red dot ,fire alarm?

Comment: I think it probably is a window inside a building; that is, I don’t particularly think it’s “inverted.”  I think original premise asks their question that because the immediately preceding scenes were revealed to be an inverted reflection, which I don’t think is intent here. I think rather they just may be showing off their graphical SFX muscle for the remake with stuff like this.